# How to maintain WFFM Field values after save action

Tags: wffm

In our requirement we need to maintain the field value after wffm submission and display success message.

we are using custom save action to pass the form values to services. once the values is passed we are showing a success message.

Now only the success message is displayed and form fields value disappears. Is there a way to retain the field values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your field values into session. It will be retained even after the submission. If you want to show your field values in success message i suggest you to redirect to a success page having a custom component which will use the session values and show the success message. There is a very nice blog you can check that for reference.

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/06/14/show-submitted-web-forms-for-marketers-form-field-values-on-a-confirmation-page-in-sitecore/