# WFFM - Dynamic field in Success Message

Tags: wffm

We are using Sitecore 8.2 Update 4, and I have the requirement to display a reference number in the success message when an enquiry is made using a WFFM form. This value will also be included in an email to the customer so Im thinking this would only be possible using a Custom Type that includes a hidden field - this control would also initialise this value to a random string.

But how then could I display this value in my "Success Message" that is displayed? This field only accepts a string (although it can contain html)

I could provide my own version of FormViewModel.cshtml to display this value but the question still remains, how could I access this variable to display?

Comment: Does it have to be a success message or is a success page also an option?

Comment: Requirements are for the success message at this stage. are you thinking that if a success page is used, I could read the ref number from the db? This answer suggests using the session for a success message : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7530/how-to-maintain-wffm-field-values-after-save-action?rq=1

Comment: Wrote a post on how to do this easily with a success page: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2016/07/sitecore-wffm-act-on-success.html